# Unable to connect to Kakfa Server from my localhost

Tags: apache-kafka

I have my Kafka Server running on other system. I am trying to run the client from my local machine by giving the broker url of the machine where Kafka server is running. But unfortunately i am not able to connect to kafka server.

`server.properties` files has the below attributes:

```
    group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
    listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093
    advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093
    #advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://10.97.123.52:9093
    security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
    sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
    sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
```

while running my client from my local machine, i am passing the broker url of the server machine, but unable to connect:( . Can anyone help in this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit simplified, but ... the client first connects to the *bootstrap* server to get the metadata. A based on that metadata it will open another TCP connection to the broker which is leader for the topic/partition the clients wants to speak with.

The first connection is done based on the bootstrap server address which you set. The second connection is opened to the address from the metadata. And the metadata will in your case contain the address from the `advertised.listeners` field, which is `localhost`. So the client will try to connect to `localhost:9093` and not to your broker. So you need to set the `advertised.listeners` to use the address under which the broker is visible for the clients. (which is maybe the line which is commented out in your config example?)

You have also the `listener` field set to listen on `localhost` only. So it will not be accessible from the external IP address. You have to change it to listen on the external IP address. Most propbably setting it to the following value (i.e. without `localhost`) should help:

```
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9093
```

Comment: Hi Jakub,thanks for the info. I have updated the name of my server machines and port no in advertised.listener and restarted the server.Now its giving me error as : Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker might not be available.

Comment: Also, where i can set the bootstrap server and what should be its value. I can see bootstrap server in producer and consumer properties files. Is it the place where i can set?

Comment: You said you are using "your client". If that is the Apache Kafka Java client, than the ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG property which you should set in the properties file and pass to the consumer / producer when creating it. For clients in different languages, it might be called / set differently.

Comment: As for the "Connection could not be established", it is hard to guess without the exact logs. But you can always start by trying to open a telnet connection to the IP address and port. I noticed in your config that your listener is set to localhost. You should probably change that as well - it should listen on all interfaces, not only on localhost if you want to connect from outside. I will update the answer with that info.

Comment: Hey Jakub,thanks a lot for the information. It is working now:)

Comment: In case anyone facing the same issue, here is the updated server.properties files:

Comment: group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9093
#advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://<full machine name where kafka server is running>:9093
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN

Comment: hi ashish i am facing same problem.